# How connect Django with SQLServer 2008 r2

Tags: python, sql-server, django

I tried connect Django with SQL Server 2008 r2 SP3.
But when y run "python manage.py migrate" i get **"django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de 'OFFSET'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)")"**

My Settings:

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "mssql",
        "NAME": "xx",
        "USER": "xx",
        "PASSWORD": "xx",
        "HOST": "xx",
        "PORT": "1433",
        "OPTIONS": {"driver": "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server", 
        },
    },
}
```

Version SQL Server: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP3) - 10.50.6000.34 (X64)
Aug 19 2014 12:21:34
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
Express Edition with Advanced Services (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3  (Build 19045: ) (Hypervisor)

Version Python: 3.8.10
Version Django: 3.1.7

Comment: *"Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de 'OFFSET'"* At a *guess* that says "incorrect syntax near OFFSET" (you need to translate that error). SQL Server 2008R2 (which has been completely unsupported for over 3 years) does not support the `OFFSET` clause; it was added in SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Should I decrement the version of django and/or python?

Comment: I would get the version of SQL Server upgraded; as I mentioned 2008R2 ran *completely* out of support many years ago.

Comment: In this project i should work with SQL Server 2008 R2 SP3

Comment: No, nobody should work with SQL Server 2008, nor even SQL Server 2012, they're both completely unsupported now.